# How to get a transparent background for plank?

Tags: release-loki, plank

Plank comes with a white background that the icons seem to hover over. Since I'm using plank on the left side of the screen, the background is not really necessary and kind of bugs me. I remember having a transparent background in freya, but I can't remember where the setting can be found and changed.

Any ideas for Loki? Thanks!

Comment: hello sir i have installed elementary loki. I am unable to make transparent any one. ppa not working its showing unable to locate. I am trying this from 2 days. Any on can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Ctrl + right click on a plank icon
2. In this menu you can now click on preferences (of plank)
3. There you can choose between some themes...choose 'transparent'

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I don't understand why they didn't include a panel for the plank settings in the system settings though...?!?

Answer (score 4):

Open the Applications menu in the search field type `plank --preferences` and then select Theme -> Transparent.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted because it's the right answer, possibly because it was only a partial answer? Anyway, I have added the final step and added a screenshot.